# AWS Athena - Query data from different years in partitions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, partitioning, amazon-athena

We have large datasets partitioned in S3 like `s3://bucket/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/file.csv`.

What would be the best way to query the data in Athena from different years and take advantage of the partitioning ?

Here's what I tried for **data from 2018-03-07 to 2020-03-06**:

**Query 1** - running for 2min 45s before I cancel

```
SELECT dt, col1, col2
FROM mytable
WHERE year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2020'
AND dt BETWEEN '2018-03-07' AND '2020-03-06'
ORDER BY dt
```

**Query 2** - run for about 2min. However I don't think it would be efficient if the period were from for example 2005 to 2020

```
SELECT dt, col1, col2
FROM mytable
WHERE (year = '2018' AND month >= '03' AND dt >= '2018-03-07')
OR year = '2019' OR (year = '2020' AND month <= '03' AND dt <= '2020-03-06')
ORDER BY dt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to repartition table by dt only (yyyy-MM-dd) instead of `year`, `month`, `day`, this is simple and partition pruning will work, though queries using year only filter like `where year>'2020'` should be rewritten as `dt>'2020-01-01'` and so on.

Also BTW in Hive partition pruning works fine with queries like this:

```
where concat(year, '-', month, '-', day) >= '2018-03-07'
      and 
      concat(year, '-', month, '-', day) <= '2020-03-06'
```

I cant check does the same works in Presto or not but it worth trying. You can use `||` operator instead of `concat()`.

Comment: I've tried with `concat` and the query took about 45s to complete. The query is like this `SELECT dt, col1, col2 FROM mytable WHERE concat(year, '-', month, '-', day) >= '2018-03-07' AND concat(year, '-', month, '-', day) <= '2020-03-06' AND dt BETWEEN '2018-03-07' AND '2020-03-06' ORDER BY dt`

Comment: @Marius Great! Then it works in Presto too

Comment: I like this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified your second query `(year > '2018' AND  year < '2020')` instead of `year='2019'` and having a condition on `day` rather than `dt`(I don't see date in partitions)?

```
SELECT *
FROM award WHERE 
(year = '2018' AND ((month = '03' AND day >= '07') OR month > '03'))
OR 
(year > '2018' AND  year < '2020') 
OR 
(year = '2020' AND (month < '03' OR (month = '03' OR day <= '06')))
```

Comment: No, that won't work for dates like `2018-04-01` and `2020-02-20`.

Comment: `dt` is a column in the CSV files.